# If S is an unbounded set of real numbers, how can I prove there is an unbounded continuous function on S?

Tags: continuity

I'm given that $S$ consists of real numbers meaning there exists x$_n$ such that either lim(x$_n$)=+∞ or lim(x$_n$)=-∞ and I'm supposed to prove that there exists an unbounded continuous function on $S$

The best that I can find is f(x)=x and that if this exists in $S$ and $S$ is unbounded, then f(x) is unbounded for all x$_n$ in $S$ and continuous because f(x)=x is continuous.
I found that solution online but it doesn't feel right. Is this enough for a proof? What can I do better?

Comment: That solution is correct, although it could be structured more formally. A small issue: "$S$ consists of real numbers" does *not* imply "there exists $\{x_n\}\subset S$ such that $x_n\to \infty$ or $x_n\to -\infty$." I would probably rephrase this with a "such that" in the middle.

Comment: You could use $f(x) = |x|$, then you don't need to deal with a negative infinity as well. $f$ is continuous and there are $x_n \in S$ such that $f(x_n) \to \infty$.